# Retrofit: Handling error JSON response

Tags: android, json, retrofit

My web server returns JSON in the following form if successful (`200` status code):

```
{"success":true,"data":{"user_id":"20","username":"Bob"}}
```

But if something went wrong (for example, if the username and password entered was too short in a form), it returns JSON in the following form (`400` status code):

```
{"success":true,"errors":{"username":["Username too short"],"password":["Incorrect password","Password too short"]}}
```

How do I handle these two different responses in [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)? This is my code so far:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(URL)
        .build();

ApiEndpointInterface api = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

api.getToken('1', new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void success(DefaultResponse json, Response response) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError response) {
        //
    }
});
```

How do I handle these two differently structured JSON responses?

Comment: So I should be returning the error response as status code `200` as well? Why? And how could I find the difference between a successful response and an error response?

Comment: if the response is a 400, then it's a failure and thus should be treated as such...
You can consider re-structuring your model, so it handles a "data" object and an "error" object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things.
First, do not return a 400 from the server. as others have stated you actually have a successful response from the server, so you just need to parse the error on your end.

your server can return a flag indicating login success or failure.
After that, you can simply add the error model to your DefaultResponse model. like so

```
public class DefaultResponse {
        public boolean success;
        public DataModel data;
        public ErrorModel errors;


    public static class DataModel {
        private String user_id;
        private String username;
    }

    public static class ErrorModel { ... }
}
```

You will still need to handle instances where your server responds with statuses other than OK, but typically error responses from a server are simple plain text, like "bad request".. You could of course insert json if you wish which you could extract from RetrofitError.getMessage(), but GSON wouldn't parse that for you automatically. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should realize that actually both responses you posted are success from the network request perspective. 
The failure status is for the request failure (Network connection error, 404, etc.) and not failure you return after trying to login the user in your backend.

You'll need to parse the result in success method and decide weather the internal result is success from your app logic perspective.

You should offcourse also handle failure().

Comment: So if my current model class looks like this, how should I modify it to also handle the errors? http://pastebin.com/nkSScAS3

Comment: consider adding  a status to your response, e,g,:
 private int statusCode;
this way the server can indicate weather the Login is a successful:
0 - Login success
1 - wrong username/password
2 - unknown error

Answer (score 0):

if you get the JSON from your web service, which mean it's success.

so, in your success method, grab the JSON and handle it

for example, from your JSON format

```
    @Override
        public void success(DefaultResponse json, Response response) {
           try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject data = json.get("data"); // if no "data" element, it will throw JSONException
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"username to short",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        }
```

or you can use [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to handle your JSON data